# .query method not working on flask-sqlalchemy model class

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I'm working with https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/ and I have this model class:

```py
from config import db


class Category(db.Model):
    """Data:
        id (int): database id
        name (string): display name
    """
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    products = db.relationship('Product', backref='category', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category %s>' % self.name
```

but .query doesn't work with this class, it say's there is no such method?
anybody know why query doesn't excists?

Comment: can you add the exact error message

Comment: My IDE (Pycharm) gives this error message: `Unresolved attribute reference 'query' for class 'Category' `

Answer (score 0):

It was my IDE that was throwing the error, when I run the script it runs fine apparently. Thanks all for your time!